# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll that inserting data into Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net, sqlcommand

I try to read session varible `Id` on myconferences page and fill the Gridview with my query but I got error that 'System.InvalidOperationException' from `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. How to fix it?
 
[image]

My codes

```
 public partial class MyConferences : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    internal User user;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();

        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        object user = Session["Id"];

        if(user != null)
        {
            user = Session["user"] as User;
        }

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "select Conferences.conferenceName , Conferences.conferencePlace , Conferences.conferenceDate , Conferences.category from Conferences inner join Users on Conferences.fk_Users = Users.Id where Users.Id =@Id";

            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ((object)user) ?? DBNull.Value);
                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();                    
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also User object on Login page.

```
  User u = new User();
                u.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
                u.Name = dr["name"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["name"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                u.Surname = dr["surname"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["surname"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                u.Email = dr["email"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["email"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                Session["user"] = u;
```

Answer (score 2):

However I couldn't get the actual exception detail in `Additional Information` because it is not in English language but what mistakes I can see directly are below

**First mistake,**

You are calling 
`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after `con.Close();` so it cannot execute the command since connection is no more open.

**Second mistake,**

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is used for insert/update queries. It will trow error since the query is returning result set which can be caught using methods like `ExecuteReader` but not by method `ExecuteNonQuery`

Actually I am not getting why you are calling it in the first place since you have already loaded data using `cmd.ExecuteReader();`.

**How to fix it**

Remove this line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And correct this line, (this is not the clean way to do it but I am writing it as per your current code)

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ((object)user) == null?(object)DBNull.Value:(object)((object)user).UserId);
```

**Edit**

The full code

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    object id = Session["Id"];

    if(id != null)
    {
        user = Session["user"] as User;
    }

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string query = "select Conferences.conferenceName , Conferences.conferencePlace , Conferences.conferenceDate , Conferences.category from Conferences inner join Users on Conferences.fk_Users = Users.Id where Users.Id =@Id";

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", user == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)user.UserId);
            con.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();                    
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant call user variables when I press the dot so I got are you missing a using directive or an assemble refence?

Comment: @user5695111 - Because I don't know for what reasons you were declaring new variable `user` of type `object` in your function which you have already declared globally as `User` class type. And since it is of `object` type, how it will have `UserId` in it. I have posted the full code. Should work for you.

Comment: Also, I am not sure why you are checking this session `Session["Id"]` and then trying to access another session `Session["user"]`. You can directly check `Session["user"]` session. But I haven't changed that part and kept it the way you used thinking you might have some logic behind it.

Comment: I can login with email and password on my website so I have email and password in my session. But this page I need to read UserId in my session  because Conference table does't have email and I can't reach this table with my session that's why I create User object with Id. In this way I can read Id.

Comment: The full code throw error "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", user == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)user.UserId);" user.UserId threw an exception of type 'system.nullreferenceexception'

Comment: Sounds not possible since I am checking if user is not null. Are you sure you are using my full code?

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to pass an object to the Users.Id field (which I assume is an int)

Try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", (int)user.UserId);
```

Comment: There is no `Id` property in his `User` class

Comment: @PawanNogariya Updated.

Comment: But you are first accessing the property of the object and then checking it null, if user is null then it will throw error. Secondly you are parsing `UserId` to `int` which is non nullable so this condition will never run

Comment: I just updated the OPs code to show what he should be passing as the parameter, but I'll update the answer.